# How to manage error message in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to spring MVC .My abc page is have one submit button. On click of submit button, abcHandler called which is inside xyzController.
Just wondering how to achieve this scenario.

-- If some error occurs then it should return some message.
-- It should stay in the same page , for me its abc page.

I have tried this.The problem I am facing is that , i am getting the alert message as "You must have something...",
but it is navigating to error page means a blank page. This is not suppose to happen.I want to show the message and stay in the same page.
How can i achieve easily with spring MVC.
Please suggest some idea.

```
public class xyzController extends MultiActionController implements InitializingBean {

public ModelAndView abcHandler(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception  {

// session
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

String abc = "";
if(abc != ""){

}else{
String error = "You must have xyzzzzzz";
return new ModelAndView("2.0/error", "downloaderror", error);
}

return new ModelAndView();
}
}
```

My error.jsp is like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="abc/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<c:if test="${not empty downloaderror}">
<script>
    alert("You must have something...");        
</script>
</c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `abc != ""` comparison will always resolve to `true`. Change it to `"".equals(abc)` or `abc.isEmpty()` of you know it cannot be `null`.

Comment: You say you are submitting something. If you're using a form you should validate using `BindingResult` and display the errors through `<form:errors path="property" />`

Answer (score 0):

On validation failure do not return to error page, instead return to same page so your code in else block should be

```
}else{ String error = "You must have xyzzzzzz";
        return new ModelAndView("2.0/error", "downloaderror", abc); }
```

And also store the errormessage in your modelmap against some key like "errormsg" and on your abc page check for this key and then print the message.

Answer (score 0):

Add an error flag in controller method like this

```
public ModelAndView abcHandler(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception  {

 ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView();
 model.addObject("error", true);

 return model;

}
```

In JSP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="abc/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<c:if test="${error}">
<script>
  alert("You must have something...");        
</script>
</c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The method addAttribute(String, boolean) is undefined for the type ModelAndView. Why is it so ? Am i using older version of Spring framework or what ?

Comment: Use addObject method to add attribute parameter.

Comment: I have tried, i am getting this error now : ModelAndView [ModelAndView: materialized View is [null]; model is {error=true}] neither contains a view name nor a View object in servlet with name 'XXXXX'

Comment: You get this error because you did not set view. Set view for model object like this model.setView("home");. Now this controller will search for home.jsp if exist otherwise it will throw an exception.

Comment: yes i have tried it,its working as you are expecting but, my button is inside a form and the form is having action which is calling this abc handler and url is differnt, so it is going to the page which is blank.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement HandlerExceptionResolver on your own.Refer to this tutorial: http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: I have tried, i am getting this error now : ModelAndView [ModelAndView: materialized View is [null]; model is {error=true}] neither contains a view name nor a View object in servlet with name 'XXXXX'

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the scenario by going in following way:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView; 

public ModelAndView abcHandler(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception  {

 ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView();
 model.addObject("ERROR_CODE", "Error Occurred");
 model.setViewName("page1");

 return model;

}
```

and your jsp page will be like following:

page1.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <body>
    <c:if test="${!empty ERROR_CODE }">
   <c:out value="${ERROR_CODE }"></c:out>
    </c:if>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Yes, i have tried the same, but it is going to page1.jsp, which is not suppose to happen. My requirement is , it should stay in the same page where it is.

Comment: my button is inside a form and the form is having action which is calling this abc handler and that url is differnt, so it is going to  page which is blank

Comment: in view name you can provide the name of your page where you have button... and you can place the <c:if> logic on your same page.